# Laravel Model - All ID's return 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get all the projects through a group. I got that working now, but I can't seem to get the right ID's. I keep getting 1 as the ID for all my posts. Am I doing something wrong?

**ProjectController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $projects = \Auth::user()->projects;
    dd($projects);
    return view('projects.home', compact('projects'));
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Project', 'App\Group',
        'id', 'group_id', 'group_id'
    );
}
```

**Dump**
(all items have the same attribute > id, all the other attributes are good)

```
Collection {#224 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => Project {#225 ▼
      #table: "projects"
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "project.com"
        "display_name" => "Project 1"
        "group_id" => 1
        "active" => 0
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => "2017-03-29 12:21:47"
      ]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Project {#226 ▶}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same ids to get them. Try to change the code to:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Project', 'App\Group',
        'id', 'user_id', 'group_id'
    );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Every user is in one group. Every group has multiple projects and multiple users.